# Cannot install lxml on Ubuntu 14

Tags: python, lxml

I have problems installing lxml on my virtual machine, cloud server, Ubuntu 14.04.2 with 512MB RAM. For people that are going through this, I will document little steps of problems that occurred on the path.

First I didn't install requirements, so make sure you have that installed. Can be found [here](http://lxml.de/installation.html#requirements).

Then I had some problems with memory, because 512MB were insufficient. Excellent post on how to extend your RAMS with swap can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334366/out-of-memory-issue-in-installing-packages-on-ubuntu-server).

Now I'm facing new problem. While trying to execute `sudo pip install lxml`.

In pip.log I've found this messsage:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Is it some "z" module that I'm missing? What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I've found what was missing.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178416/pip-install-lxml-error/5178444#5178444) you can find in one answer, that in all the requirements are actually these ones:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev python3-pip
```

After that, you can safely do `sudo pip install lxml`

Comment: Thanks, this error was driving me crazy. For me it was "zlib1g-dev" missing.